# Windows 10 hanging on reboots/shutdowns

Tags: windows-10, freeze, shutdown, reboot

I recently started to have an issue with my custom-built system. Whenever I try to reboot/shutdown in Windows 10 the system it will just hang. Unless I do a hard shut down with the power button it will not fully go down. I have reviewed the Event Viewer and there are no errors that indicate an improper shutdown but the complete opposite:

```
    The kernel power manager has initiated a shutdown transition.

    Shutdown Reason: Kernel API
    ------
    The operating system is shutting down at system time ‎2020‎-‎07‎-‎15T03:52:50.768915400Z.
    ------ 
    The operating system started at system time ‎2020‎-‎07‎-‎15T04:42:03.500000000Z.
```

When the system does go down for reboot I see that the RGB in my keyboard/mouse peripherals shuts off. However, the RGB in my memory modules is still active the entire time if I try to do a shutdown from Windows 10.

I tried to do a reimage with a fresh ISO created from the Windows Media Creation Tool, and this still resulted in the same issue. The only external devices I have recently added to my system was an Elgato HD 60S and a Oculus Rift S. As well I did upgrade from a GTX 1050 TI to a GTX 1070 TI Founders Edition. My system specs are listed below:

```
Motherboard: Gigabyte Aorus B450 PRO WiFi 
CPU: Ryzen 5 1500X 
Memory: GSkills Trident 16GB 3200 
GPU: Nvidia GTX 1070 TI Founders Edition
Disk: Western Digital M.2
Power Supply: 750 Watt PSU
```

Answer (score 0):

I just disabled Fast Startup and now I am having no issues.

https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.howtogeek.com/349114/shutting-down-doesnt-fully-shut-down-windows-10-but-restarting-it-does/amp/

Answer (score 0):

There's a thread on Reddit about this issue, it can be BIOS related:
https://www.reddit.com/r/computers/comments/cvxapf/anybody_know_why_my_ram_stays_lit_when_in_sleep/